# Pass Information from Cookie into Drift Custom Attribute

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-tag-manager, drift

I need a little help.

I am trying to pass data from a Cookie inside of GTM to a custom attribute inside of Drift.

I've tried following this documentation, but can't seem to get it to work:
https://devdocs.drift.com/docs/contact-properties

This is the code that I have tried using inside of Google Tag Manager:

```js
drift.on('ready', function() {
  drift.api.setUserAttributes({
    gclid: '{{cookie - gclid}}'
  })
})
```

I am not very familiar with coding, so I am sure there is some error on my end. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite challenging to help without knowing what the errors are, but I'll do my best.

The issue is most likely related to either the Drift integration failing to initialize or an error related to accessing the cookie. The best way to solve your issue would be to isolate where the problem lies.

Focussing on Drift, are you sure that Drift has been initialized correctly?

According to the [documentation](https://devdocs.drift.com/docs/contact-properties), a custom Drift attribute will be visible in the Custom attributes tab in your [contact settings](https://app.drift.com/contacts/contact-settings).

You can test this by running the following code snippet in the browser console for the website in question and then checking the Custom attributes tab to check that the `test` attribute has been created.

```
drift.on('ready', function() {drift.api.setUserAttributes({test: 'tester',})})
```

Note that Drift does not initialize when running a website locally so make sure that you're testing with a site that's deployed to a server.

If the above works then we know that Drift is working as expected and the issue relates to how you're accessing the cookie so you'll want to focus on that.

In either case, if you could share your error, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I tried running the test like you suggested on Chrome - but the test attribute was not created. When I ran the test on my browser console, it returned "undefined".

Comment: The `undefined` response is correct. Are you running your site locally? The reason I ask is that, due to limitations with Drift, the attribute is not created while running a site locally, but if you try create the attribute when running your site on a server, the attribute should be correctly created.

Comment: So - I ran a test for gclid using that code above, except I replaced it with gclid (the custom action that I set up. `drift.on('ready', function() {drift.api.setUserAttributes({gclid: 'gclid-test',})})` This worked. The issue must be with how I am pulling in the cookie.

Comment: That's good news that the test attribute has been created and would suggest that the issue is related to how you're parsing the cookie. So to confirm, the test attribute is correctly created in Drift along with the value for a specific user? If so, what is the error that you get when trying to set the attribute to the value of the cookie?

Comment: My thought is the issue must specifically be with how I am trying to access the cookie in Google Tag Manager. I have a 1st Party Cookie Variable called `cookie - gclid` that I am trying to use. However, I am not quite sure how to write it in the above function. I have tried what is in my original post along with `drift.on('ready', function() {drift.api.setUserAttributes({gclid: {{cookie - gclid}},})})`, but neither pull in the gclid. I also wonder if this is an issue because I am using Google Tag Manager instead of doing something directly on the site.

Comment: I am not seeing a specific error per-se. I think this is because I am doing it in Google Tag Manager. You seem to have more knowledge and experience on this stuff than I do - so where would you expect to see an error (or where would the error even display?).

Comment: I would expect to see the error in the browser console. Have you checked there?